# Error at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse - NodeJS passport google oauth2.0

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to embed google authentication in Node.js using passport and google passport-google-oauth20.  The problem is that when the google callback route opens up I get:

```
Error
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (E:\Programowanie\NodeJS\Hydronide\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:329:12)
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (E:\Programowanie\NodeJS\Hydronide\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:376:16)
at E:\Programowanie\NodeJS\Hydronide\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:166:45
at E:\Programowanie\NodeJS\Hydronide\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:191:18
at passBackControl (E:\Programowanie\NodeJS\Hydronide\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\Programowanie\NodeJS\Hydronide\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I (more or less) follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users).
Here is my code:
Routes (starting with '/auth')

```
'use strict'

const passport = require('passport')
const router = require('express').Router()

router.get(
  '/google',
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query.return) {
      req.session.oauth2return = req.query.return
    }
    next()
  },
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email', 'profile'] })
)

router.get(
  '/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google'),
  (req, res) => {
    const redirect = req.session.oauth2return || '/';
    delete req.session.oauth2return;
    res.redirect(redirect);
  }
);

module.exports = router
```

There is a passport configuration:

```
'use strict'
const passport = require('passport')
const keys = require('./keys')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const userController = require('../controllers/user-controller')

const passportConfig = {
  clientID: keys.google.clientId,
  clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: 'auth/google/callback',
  accessType: 'offline'
}

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(passportConfig,
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  console.log(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
  userController.getUserByExternalId('google', profile.id)
  .then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      userController.createUser(profile, 'google')
      .then(user => {
        return done(null, user)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return done(err)
      })
    }
    return done(null, user)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return done(err)
  })
}))

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
  cb(null, user)
})
passport.deserializeUser((obj, cb) => {
  cb(null, obj)
})
```

As you can see I've added console.log in the new GoogleStrategy second parameter function, but it never fires.

//EDIT
I noticed that instead of assign `require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy` I used `require('passport-google-oauth20')`. But fixing it doesn't chang anything, still the same error.
What I can add to a question is that in my main fail I call

```
// sets passport config
require('./config/jwt-auth')
require('./config/google-auth')

// initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize())
```

So I don't expect anything wrong in there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to specify the full url in the callbackURL section of the strategy:
for example: when if running the code locally on `localhost:3000` with code like this:

```
passport.use(new googleStrategy({
    clientID:keys.clientID,
    clientSecret:keys.clientSecret,
    callbackURL:'auth/google/callback'
},(accessToken,refreshToken, profile,done)=>{
    console.log(accessToken);
    console.log(refreshToken);
    console.log(profile);
}
));

app.get('/auth',passport.authenticate('google',{

    scope:['profile','email']
}));
app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google'));
```

The above code will surely throw a TokenError: Bad request. You have to pass the complete URl to have a final code like shown below:

```
passport.use(new googleStrategy({
    clientID:keys.clientID,
    clientSecret:keys.clientSecret,
    callbackURL:'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback'
},(accessToken,refreshToken, profile,done)=>{
    console.log(accessToken);
    console.log(refreshToken);
    console.log(profile);
}
));

app.get('/auth',passport.authenticate('google',{
    scope:['profile','email']
}));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get help by putting some console.log inside your Oauth and Strategy under node modules, Specifically around the line on which you are getting error in logs.

```
E:\Programowanie\NodeJS\Hydronide\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js
E:\Programowanie\NodeJS\Hydronide\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js
```

This will help you to get the root cause of parsing error . Seems like there is some problem with request/response data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by checking this route

```
app.get('/auth',passport.authenticate('google',{
    scope:['profile','email']
}));
```

I was trying to do something to new users and for that I was trying to get the users from the database if I get that I will do that work otherwise simply redirect to somewhere but the problem I faced is
you can check this route by consoling the log

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { User } = require('../models/user.model');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/config.json');
const role = require('../lib/role');


const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

router.use(passport.initialize());

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
  cb(null, user);
});


passport.deserializeUser((obj, cb) => {
  cb(null, obj);
});


passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: "sssssssssssssssssssssssssss",
  clientSecret: "Vsssssssssssssss",
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/api/auth/google/callback"
},

  (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {

    User.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        cb(err); // handle errors!
      }
      if (!err && user !== null) {
        cb(err, user);
      }
      else {

        user = new User({
          googleId: profile.id,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          firstname: profile.name.givenName,
          lastname: profile.name.familyName,
          role: role.Client,
          isActive: true,
          isGain: false,
        });

        user.save((err) => {
          if (err) {
            cb(err); // handle errors!
          } else {
            cb(null, user);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
));



router.get('/', passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

// callback
router.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/failed' }),
  (req, res) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: req.user._id, email: req.user.email, role: req.user.role }, config.secret_key, { expiresIn: '10 h' })
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, token, expireIn: `${new Date().getTime() + 120000}` })
  }
);


//failed auth google 
router.get('/failed', async (req, res) => { res.status(404).send('erreur authentification') })





module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

In passport.js you need to change callbackURL from 'auth/google/callback' to '/auth/google/callback'. Do not forget to add '/' before auth.

```js
passport.use(new googleStrategy({
    clientID:keys.clientID,
    clientSecret:keys.clientSecret,
    callbackURL:'/auth/google/callback'
},(accessToken,refreshToken, profile,done)=>{
    console.log(accessToken);
    console.log(refreshToken);
    console.log(profile);
}
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/home"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        console.log(profile);
        User.findOrCreate({ username: profile.displayName, googleId: profile.id }, 
    function (err, user) {
        return cb(err, user);
    });
}));
```

Comment: If you look closely, you'll realize that you wrote the same code as the author.
Consider working closely with error messages, before proffering any solution